# Are there in this graph self-loop? And if yer how can i remove it and check the isomorphism with another graph that have not self-loop?

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, subgraph, isomorphism

Hi all I am checking if G2 is a subgraph isomorphism of G1, If I plot them I can clearly see the isomorphism but if I use the function I can False. Anyone know why? I think that the reason are the self-loop in the rectangular graph but I don't know how to remove them [image: G2]
[image: G1]

In python I've drawn them like that:

```
L =[[ 0,   23.4,  30.3,  49.45,  0,    0,    0,   0,    0,    0,    0],
 [23.4,   0,   34.42, 39.54, 34.26,  0,    0,    0,    0,    0 ,   0  ],
 [30.3,  34.42,  0,   26.67, 42.71, 79.12,  0,    0,    0 ,   0,    0  ],
 [49.45, 39.54 ,26.67,  0,   22.98 ,65.57 ,44.53,  0,    0,    0,    0  ],
 [ 0,  34.26 ,42.71 ,22.98 , 0 ,  43.04 ,23.19, 47.2,   0 ,   0   , 0  ],
 [ 0 ,   0   ,79.12 ,65.57, 43.04,  0,   30.29 ,29.14, 64.72 , 0 ,   0  ],
 [ 0  ,  0    ,0   ,44.53 ,23.19 ,30.29  ,0,   24.19, 60.59, 49.7,   0  ],
 [ 0   , 0   , 0    ,0 ,  47.2  ,29.14 ,24.19 , 0,   39.03 ,46.27 ,40.06],
 [ 0 ,   0  ,  0,    0  ,  0  , 64.72, 60.59 ,39.03 , 0   ,44.72 ,62.05],
 [ 0  ,  0 ,   0 ,   0   , 0 ,   0 ,  49.7  ,46.27 ,44.72 , 0 ,  30.7 ],
 [ 0   , 0,    0  ,  0    ,0,    0  ,  0 ,  40.06, 62.05, 30.7  , 0  ]]

A1 = np.array(L)
A2 = np.array([[0,30,0,0,0,0], [0,0,30,0,0,0], [0,0,0,30,0,0],[30,0,0,0,0,0],[30,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,30,30,0]])
G1 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A1)
G2 = nx.from_numpy_matrix(A2)
GM = isomorphism.GraphMatcher(G1,G2)
print(GM.subgraph_is_isomorphic())
```

Answer (score 0):

This function https://graspologic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/utils.html#graspologic.utils.remove_loops will give you back a graph without loops, though it will return an adjacency matrix. If you prefer to do this on the networkx representation, you could always iterate through the edges and just check whether the source node is equal to the target node.

I can't speak to the isomorphism part, I'm not sure where you're getting the function `isomorphism.GraphMatcher()`

Answer (score 0):

I Noticed that the algorithm is not able to find the isomorphism because in the rectangle are missing the diagonal edge.